# How do I Store a String to a file in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to store a String to a file which should be stored on the device

I have the following code that stores the String into a variable called exportstring:

```
final JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonArray;
JSONObject export = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(index);
String exportString = export.toString();
writeToFile(exportString);
```

I then have a function called `writeToFile`

```
private void writeToFile(String content) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.append(content);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

when I run it, I get a message coming up saying "The file was saved"

but when I open a file manager, I do not see it anywhere.

where is the file saved to?

or have I done something wrong here?

Comment: you have empty `catch` block, that's why you don't see the problem. Never ignore exceptions in catch block

Comment: what does that mean

Comment: that means that if your code is throwing the exception, you will never know about it. At least do `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Its saved in external directory. You might want to double check if you are browsing internal or external storage directory through the file browser.

Comment: ok, well I would like it to store the file in for example /storage/emulated/0/Download

Comment: saving a string to shared preferences will also be a file io.

Answer (score 0):

To store the file in Downloads folder, change:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.txt");
```

to:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/test.txt");
```

UPDATE:  **Before** trying to save the file you should make sure you have the required permissions, in this case the permission to write to storage. Below is a short example of how to do that:

```
protected boolean checkPermission() {
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

protected void requestPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store files. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
            }
        }
    }


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("permissionCheck", "Permission Granted, do what you want to do when user grants the permission here!!!");

                } else {
                    Log.d("permissionCheck", "Permission Denied, do what you want to do when user denies the permission here...");
                }      
                break;
        }
    }
```

Include the code above to your activity (or any activity before the one you currently are at) and **before** trying to store the string to the file do the following:

```
if(!checkPermission()){
   Log.d("permissionCheck", "Need to get the permissions");
   requestPermission();
}else{
   Log.d("permissionCheck", "Already have the permissions");
}
```

To see the logs in logcat :

[image]

Comment: Hi, I changed it and it still does not save it in the folder /storage/emulated/0/Download

Comment: Then make sure you have taken the necessary permission to read/write to storage.   `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.   Make sure you declare it in your Manifest file AND request the permission on run time.

Comment: Also in your catch block try to log the caught exception if there is one, so you can easily figure out what's wrong!

Comment: Only in the manifest? It is not enought if you are targeting new versions of Android. You need to ask for the permission at one of your activities as well. Do you do that?

Comment: Yes, only in the Manifest, how do I do this in the activity

Comment: See my updated answer to get the permissions you need!

Comment: cool, thanks a lot, however it still does not do anything not even ask for permissions

Comment: You pasted the 3 methods in your code, run `if(!checkPermission()){
   requestPermission();
}` and no dialog appeared?

Comment: I updated my answer to include some logs. Run it again and tell my which log you saw (Need to get the permissions/Already have the permissions)

Comment: yes, I pasted the long part of your answer at the very bottom, just before the final closing brace and the other smaller snippet like this :` if(!checkPermission()){
                            requestPermission();
                        }else {
                            writeToFile(exportString);
                        }`

Comment: Please do it again, with the logs this time and tell me which log you saw

Comment: I looked at the logs and nothing is being outputted

Comment: This is not possible. Open the logcat ( bottom-left), choose your device,process and tag to see the logs generated.